# Constant in Sobolev Inequality behaviour when subdividing the domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and assume that the Sobolev inequality holds for a function $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\| f \|_{L^{p*}}\leq C(\Omega)\| \nabla f \|_{L^{p}}$.

Is it true that if I restrict $f$ to smaller and smaller subdomains $\Omega'$ of $\Omega$ in such a way that the diameter goes to $0$ and then consider the Sobolev inequality on that domain (i.e. $\| f \|_{L^{p*}}\leq C(\Omega')\| \nabla f \|_{L^{p}}$) , then the constant $C(\Omega')$ goes to zero as well?

Comment: Check what happens if you replace $f$ by $f_\epsilon:=f(x/\epsilon)$

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite get the comment because I want to make the domain smaller but keep the same function!

Comment: You could choose $\Omega=B_1(0)$ and $\Omega'=B_\epsilon(0)$. Then take $f\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, then $f_\epsilon\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega')$. And you can study how the constant scales with $\epsilon$

Comment: Thanks again, I tried, but I seem to be unable to proceed because I would need to know how $f$ and $f_{\varepsilon}$ are related. I believe the correct estimate should be that it rescales as $\varepsilon^{-p}$ right?

Comment: Ahhh nevermind, I could just change variables. I feel dumb now haha, Thank you very much for the tips.

Comment: mmm It's weird I actually get that the constant stays the same. Is this correct?

Comment: yes :) ...............